Code editor-script console missing
I am new to using Google Earth Engine.
My problem is that my Code Editor appears to be missing the script console which is the place to enter the code.
I created a new project and enabled the Earth Engine API for it. What I see is only the map with a few related buttons as below.


In Google Earth Engine find the box with dots and drag down will show the console..
like:


